# posting html code to MySQL database in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textarea on my page, and I want to type html into it and post it into my database, but I'm not sure how to convert it to a string where it will post into the DB.

It looks like in PHP, you use  mysql_real_escape_string()...but I'm not sure how this would work in C#.

Is there something similar in C#?

I'm not using Entity Framework or linq2sql...I'm just passing the value of the textarea to the controller method and posting it to the DB with just straight SQL -> INSERT command.

Comment: Depends entirely on the data access technology you're using.  Things like Entity Framework or Linq2Sql, or even parameterized queries in ADO.NET, will all escape the input for the resulting SQL query.  It has nothing to do with MVC (which is a front-end technology) or even with C# in general (in which a `string` is a `string` and isn't special based on what's in the `string`).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use

```
 System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(textArea1.text);
```

and save the string returned by the above method in MySql where `textArea1` is the id of the text area.

This works for any database.